# How to store data in an array using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I need to store data coming from an api in a variable. Only data that contains "true". I have given the API output below.

**API Output Data**

```
     {
      "BNG-JAY-137-003": false,
       "BNG-JAY-137-004": true, 
        "BNG-JAY-137-005": false 
       }
```

Below is my function. In this I need to store only data which is true in a variable.  Here `selected_data` is a variable which contains API data.

```
    on(){
    for(let key in this.selected_data) {
        if(this.selected_data[key]) {
       // here I need to store data which is true in an array.
       }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One would be to use `Object.keys` and `filter`:

```js
const selected_data = this.selected_data
const array = Object.keys(selected_data).filter(key => selected_data[key])
```

Closer to your original code would be to just `push` the keys onto an array:

```js
const selected_data = this.selected_data
const array = []

for (const key in selected_data) {
  if (selected_data[key]) {
    array.push(key)
  }
}
```

From a Vue perspective this would probably be implemented as a computed property, returning the relevant array at the end. Alternatively it might be stored in a `data` property, using something equivalent to `this.propertyName = array` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed property:

```
computed: {
    valid_selected_data: function() {
        return Object.keys(this.selected_data).reduce((acc, key) => {
            if(this.selected_data[key]) {
                acc[key] = this.selected_data[key];
            }

            return acc;
        }, {});
    }
}
```

That code will create another object which holds the same items of your `selected_data` object, but only the true ones.

If you want just an array with the true keys, then try this:

```
computed: {
    valid_selected_data: function() {
        return Object.keys(this.selected_data).filter((key) => this.selected_data[key]);
    }
}
```